# Haskell trying to implement null function on if

Tags: haskell

So basically i have a question for ym homework that says: "Create a function that checks if a list is not empty using prelude functions"
I saw the null function and i wanted to use it and print the message. 
So i tried the following:

```
notEmpty :: [Int] -> [Char]
notEmpty [x] = if (null[x]) then "False" else "True"
```

If i call notEmpty [ ], it gives me this error: Non.Exhaustive patterns in function notEmpty
after several learning i came up with this:

```
notEmpty :: [Int] -> [Char]
notEmpty [] = "False"
notEmpty [x] = if (null[x])then "False" else "True"
```

but after this, i tried the following input: notEmpty[1,2] and it gave me the same error.

My question is, when i run null [1,2] it gives me False, so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: As soon as the first definition fails to pattern-match, you already *know* the argument in the second definition is *not* empty. `notEmpty [] = "False"; notEmpty _ = "True"`.

Comment: @chepner But that isn't "using prelude functions".

Comment: @JosephSible `notEmpty [] = const "False" "joe"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[x]` doesn't mean "a list called `x`". It means "a list with one element, where the one element is called `x`". Just use `x` instead of `[x]`, and your first way will work:

```
notEmpty :: [Int] -> [Char]
notEmpty x = if (null x) then "False" else "True"
```

Comment: Omg! Can´t believe that! Thanks a lot sir! You saved my day!

Comment: @bluewolfxD If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted with the check mark icon.